# Tableau: numeric values determined as strings

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I've just started my learning with Tableau. For exercise, I downloaded a video game sales dataset from Kaggle. Tableau automatically determined the Sales columns as strings, which should be Number instead.
[image: Sales columns determined as Strings]

I tried to convert them by clicking the "Abc" icon above and choosing Number, but then it turned out that values would become NULL.
Would appreciate any idea about the possible reason and solutions :)
[image: Converting to Number]
[image: NULL]

Answer (score 0):

**Two approaches might help**

The first is to filter out non-numeric values with a formula.

Tableau "guesses" the field type based on the first 10k or so rows in the dataset. It often chooses text if a mostly numerical field contains non-numeric entries (for example "n/a" for null values). The easy solution is identify the text values and create a new field with a formula like `IF sales = 'n/a' then 0 else int(sales) end`. The new field will have numerical values you can use normally.

But it is also possible that the raw data contains rogue characters that are not visible in the source file like rogue spaces or other non-printing characters . It is worth testing the source for this (or try counting the number of characters in the imported field to see whether there are more characters than the visible number which is a sign of rogue characters in the source string). If you can identify some odd characters, they can also be filtered out using the first approach and Tableau string functions or they can be edited out of the source.